# SQL запрос для переноса значения из одной таблицы в другую по id

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте!

Есть две таблицы:

Table1

```
   +------------+----------------------------
   | id         | Annotation1   |  Text     | 
   +------------+----------------------------
   | 12         |               |      34   |
   | 13         |               |      12   |
   | 2032       |               |      51   |
   +------------+----------------------------
```

Table2

```
   +------------+----------------
   | id         | Annotation2   |  
   +------------+----------------
   | 12         | текст 1       |
   | 13         | текст2        | 
   | 2032       | текст 3       |  
   +------------+----------------
```

Подскажите какой написать SQL запрос, чтобы в колонку Annotation1 записать значения из Annotation2 в соответствии с **id** ?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел сам:

```
UPDATE 
     prefix_topic, 
     prefix_topic_content
SET 
     prefix_topic.annotation = prefix_topic_content.annotation
WHERE
     prefix_topic.id = prefix_topic_content.id;
```